# How to use ssh for svn checkout in phpstorm

Tags: svn, phpstorm

The svn repository I need to checkout from uses ssh: protocol, not http:, but the svn checkout dialog in phpstorm disables the checkout button if http:// is not used for the repository location.

Comment: `svn+ssh://...` should work fine in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 4):

Subversion **has no support** for pure ssh:// protocol. Repositories may have `http://` `file:///` `svn://` `svn+ssh://` RA-layers only

Comment: That was it... svn+ssh://  Thanks!